# Segmentation fault with yacc/bison

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am trying to write a simple HTTP request parser for a school assignment but I have this segmentation fault that I can't get rid of. I think that my production rules are ok. I have executed bison with tracing enabled and it always produces a segfault at part where it parses my header:

```
Reducing stack by rule 9 (line 59):
   $1 = token ID ()
   $2 = token COLON ()
   $3 = token STRING ()
[4]    36661 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./problem1 < input.txt
```

Here is the content of my request.l file:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include "request.tab.h"
    char *strclone(char *str);
%}

num                                     [0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?
letter                                  [a-zA-Z]
letternum                               [a-zA-Z0-9\-]
id                                      {letter}{letternum}*
string                                  \"[^"]*\"
fieldvalue                              {string}|{num}

%%

(GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|DELETE|OPTIONS)      { yylval = strclone(yytext); return METHOD; }
HTTP\/{num}                             { yylval = strclone(yytext); return VERSION; }
{id}                                    { yylval = strclone(yytext); return ID; }
"/"                                     { return SLASH; }
"\n"                                    { return NEWLINE; }
{string}                                { yylval = strclone(yytext); return STRING; }
":"                                     { return COLON; }
[ \t\n]+                                       ;
. {
    printf("Unexpected: %c\nExiting...\n", *yytext);
    exit(0);
}

%%

char *strclone(char *str) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *clone = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strcpy(clone,str);
    return clone;
}
```

and my request.y file:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define YYSTYPE char*

extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();
extern FILE* yyin;

void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

%token METHOD
%token SLASH
%token VERSION
%token STRING
%token ID
%token COLON
%token NEWLINE

%%

REQUEST: METHOD URI VERSION NEWLINE HEADERS {
       printf("%s %s", $1, $2);
    }
;

URI: SLASH DIR {
        $$ = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen($2)+1));
        sprintf($$, "//%s", $2);
    }
;

DIR: ID SLASH {
        $$ = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen($1)+2));
        sprintf($$, "%s//", $1);
    }
    |ID {
        $$ = $1;
    }
    | {
        $$ = "";
    }
;

HEADERS: HEADER {
        $$ = $1;
    }
    |HEADER NEWLINE HEADERS {
        $$ = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen($1)+1+strlen($3)+1));
        sprintf($$, "%s\n%s", $1, $3);
    }
    |{
        $$ = "";
    }
;

HEADER: ID COLON STRING {
        $$ = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen($1)+1+strlen($2)+1));
        sprintf($$, "%s:%s", $1, $3);
    }
;

%%

void yyerror (char const *s) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Poruka nije tacna\n");
}

int main() {
    yydebug = 1;
    yyin = stdin;

    do {
        yyparse();
    } while(!feof(yyin));

    return 0;
}
```

Also here is the content of my input.txt I am passing in as input:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: "developer.mozzila.org"
Accept-language: "fr"
```

Comment: `strclone()`? Have you heard of `strdup()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `request.y`, you include the directive

```
#define YYSTYPE char*
```

So in the parser code generated by Bison, `yylval` is of type `char*`. But that line is not inserted into `request.l`. So in the scanner code generated by Flex, `yylval` has its default type, `int`.

You could fix this by adding the definition of `YYSTYPE` to your `request.l` file but then you have the same setting repeated in two places, which is a recipe for disaster. Instead, use Bison`s declaration syntax:

```
%define api.value.type { char* }
```

(Note: that's a Bison declaration, not a C preprocessor define, so it goes with your other Bison `%` directives.)

The advantage of this solution is that Bison also adds the declaration to the header file it produces. Since that file is `#include`d in `request.l`, no modifications need to be made to your scanner.

C, unfortunately, allows a pointer to be converted to an integer type even if the integer type is too narrow to hold the entire address, which is the case with a typical 64-bit platform with 8-byte pointers and 4-byte `int`. So in your scanner, setting the value of what the compiler thinks is a four-byte `int` to an eight-byte pointer means that the value will be truncated. So when the parser attempts to use it as an address, you'll get a segfault. If you're lucky.

Most C compilers will warn you about this truncation -- but only if you tell the compiler that you want to see warnings (`-Wall` for clang and gcc). Compiling with `-Wall` is always important, even when compiling the output of a code generator.

You also need to fix the typo noted by [@JakobStark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17862371/jakob-stark).

Answer (score 1):

```
HEADER: ID COLON STRING {
    $$ = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen($1)+1+strlen($2)+1));
    sprintf($$, "%s:%s", $1, $3);
};
```

Shouldn't you use `strlen($3)` in the expression, where you calculate the length of the combined string? `strlen($2)` as you use will only return the length of the colon string which should be 1. If you then `sprintf` to the buffer which is too short, you access the buffer behind it's length.

Comment: Not quite but essentially correct. The Flex pattern which returns `COLON` doesn't modify `yylval`, on the assumption that the `COLON` token's semantic value will never be used. So at that point, `yylval` will still have the value it was assigned in the previous token, `ID`. Its length is still wrong, so that doesn't change the essence of your answer. However, I'll bet that is *not* the undefined behaviour which leads to the segfault. Compiling with `-Wall` is always important, even when compiling the output of a code generator.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. One of the mistakes alongside the bigger one pointed out by @rici

Comment: Another issue I see with your code is that you never free all your malloc'ed memoyr. I'm no expert in flex/bison, but couldn't you just use the yytext variable to access the lexed strings in your parser. That way you would not have to clone the string each time, and you would not need to worry about the yylval type as yytext already is of pointer type.

Comment: @JakobStark: the problem with that is that `yytext` is only valid until the next call to yylex.  So any pointer into it you save in yylval will quickly become dangling and invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too in the past few days. I was trying to imatate the /bison/examples/c/glr. I used a union as value type.
I got this error because the return type of token defined in lexer.l is not 1 of the union.struct types, and flex will not warn the mistake.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35673583)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).